# jQuery dialog not opening from subsequent datatables pages

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

Working on an MVC 3 application for our call center to display data for insurance policy holders.

I have a page with insurance claims sorted in a datatable. The table script is:

```
$('#claims').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bSort": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<"H"lrp>t<"F"ip>',
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "oLanguage": { "sZeroRecords": "No claims found for this policy", 
                       "sProcessing": "<img src='../../../../Content/images/ajax-loader-bar.gif' />" },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sName": "Claim #" },
            { "sName": "Status" },
            { "sName": "Clm Type" },
            { "sName": "Rider Form" },
            { "sName": "Primary DX" },
            { "sName": "Exam Code" },
            { "sName": "Asst Exam" },
            { "sName": "Case Mgr" },
            { "sName": "Follow Up Date" },
            { "sName": "Close/Deny Date" },
            { "sName": "Closed Reason" }
        ]

    });
```

One of the rows contains a button that opens a dialog window with details about that claim. The javascript is as such:

```
$(function () {

        $('#ClaimsDetailDialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 950,
            resizable: true,
            modal: true,
            position: ['center', 'top']
        });

        $('.claimmodal').on("click", function () {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            var claimnum = $(this).text();
            var policynum = $(this).attr('polnum');
            $('#ClaimsDetailDialog').html("<img src='../../../../Content/images/ajax-loader-bar.gif' />")
                .dialog("option", "title", "Claim Details for Claim #" + claimnum + " for Policy #" + policynum)
                .dialog("option", "buttons", {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                })
                .load(url).dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

This works fine, until there are more than 10 claims against a policy. Once a user clicks to the second page, clicking the Claim number no longer opens a dialog but instead opens the window to the requested URL, with no javascript markup.

Here is the Razor for the cell in question:

```
<td style="text-align: center">
    @Html.ActionLink(@item.Claimmast.CLMNO.ToString(), "ClaimDetail", null, new { id = item.Claimmast.ID }, new { @class = "claimmodal", polnum = item.Claimmast.POLICY }) 
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delegation since you are dynamically changing the dom..

```
$('#claims').on('click','.claimmodal',function(){
    // your code here
});
```

depending on which version of jQuery you are using

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Still new to web development so I'm fuzzy on dynamic event handling as such. I will mark as accepted as soon as I can

Comment: Your welcome.  Whenever you are changing the dom dynamically.. You should always attach your event handler to an element that is a static parent in the dom.  It will then listen for the event as they bubble up the dom tree